# Eigen-decompostion involved with a semi-orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality, matrix-decomposition

Let $V$ be a $m$ by $n$ ($m>n$) semi-orthogonal matrix, i.e. $V^TV=I_n$
Can we say something about eigen-decomposition of $V^TPV$ where $P$ is a semi-positive definite matrix?
Result would be function of $V$ and eigen-values and eigen-vectors of $P$.
If not, can we say something about the smallest $d$ eigen-values of  $V^TPV$ and the corresponding eigen-vectors provided that $d<n$?
I only think of utilizing Cauchy's interlacing property.
Let $U$ be a basis of orthogonal complement of span{$V$'s columns}, i.e. $[V ,U]$ be the basis of $\mathbb{R^m}$
$V^TPV$ is the principal $n$ by $n$ submatrix of $[V ,U]^TP[V ,U]$ and then apply the interlacing property.
But the bound it provided is too loose and it doesn't tell anything about eigenvectors.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: the conjugation by $V$ is the projection on a $n$ dimensional subspace. Cauchy's interlacing property already gives you the best bounds you could hope for

Comment: @Exodd Sorry, I don't understand why it is best bound, could you give more insight?

Answer (score 1):

As Exodd's comment mentions, Cauchy's interlacing property gives the best possible bounds. This is rigorously stated in Horn and Johnson's *Matrix Analysis* (second edition) as follows.

> **Theorem 4.3.21:** Let $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$ and $\mu_1,\dots,\mu_{n+1}$ be real numbers that satisfy the interlacing inequalities
> $$
> \mu_1 \leq \lambda_1 \leq \mu_2 \leq \lambda_2 \leq \cdots \leq \lambda_{n-1} \leq \mu_{n} \leq \lambda_{n} \leq \mu_{n+1}.
> $$
> Let $\Lambda = \operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\dots, \lambda_n)$. A real number $a$ and a real vector $y \in \Bbb R^n$ may be chosen such that the eigenvalues of
> $$
> A = \pmatrix{\Lambda & y\\ y^T & a} \in M_{n + 1}(\Bbb R)
> $$
> are $\mu_1,\dots,\mu_{n+1}$.

Comment: I see. Can we know something about eigenvectors?

Comment: If you know the eigenvalues of both matrices and the eigenvectors of the submatrix, you can describe the eigenvectors of the larger matrix using the identities [compiled in this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.03795)

Comment: Could you see my old post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4105479/show-an-iterative-method-converges-involved-with-kronecker-product-and-svd)? I can't figure out how to deal with the $Vh$ in $f$. Sorry I copied the wrong site, I edited it.